# Upgrading RN project from 0.46.4 to 0.60.0 and run in VSCode result Can't get fulfillment value from any promise, all promises were rejected

Tags: react-native, npm, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

Just upgraded my react-native project from version `0.46.4` to `0.60.0` using `yarn` or `npm` and run with visual studio code result following error.

> [Error] Error: Can't get fulfillment value from any promise, all promises were rejected.

This is my old `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ShoppingApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "2.2.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.4",
    "react-native-grid-view": "https://github.com/lucholaf/react-native-grid-view.git",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "https://github.com/ihor/react-native-scalable-image.git",
    "react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.0",
    "react-navigation": "https://github.com/Maxeh/react-navigation.git",
    "rn-viewpager": "https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "3.0.2",
    "jest": "21.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

And my new `package.json` here

```
{
  "name": "ShoppingApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.0",
    "react-native-grid-view": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "rn-viewpager": "^1.2.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "3.0.2",
    "jest": "21.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

When I build my project with Visual Studio Code, show following error.

> [Error] Error: Can't get fulfillment value from any promise, all promises were rejected.

Please let me upgrade my project and build it.

Answer (score 0):

I found way to upgrade.
I changed dependencies carefully like following package.json.

```
{
  "name": "ShoppingApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.0",
    "react-native-grid-view": "https://github.com/lucholaf/react-native-grid-view.git",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "https://github.com/ihor/react-native-scalable-image.git",
    "react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "https://github.com/Maxeh/react-navigation.git",
    "rn-viewpager": "https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

As you can see I removed native-base and updated dev dependencies and add babel/core.
And delete node_modules, yarn or npm again.